# GWT - image.getHeight() and image.getWidth() does not work on the first load

Tags: java, gwt

I'm new to GWT and was wondering why I'm not able to get this working.

I am trying to resize a large image into a smaller one, while retaining the aspect ratio with the following code:

```
Image image = new Image(myImageResource.getURL());
image.setPixelSize(newWidth, myImageResource.getHeight() * newWidth / myImageResource.getWidth());
```

But what happens is that, `myImageResource.getHeight()` and `myImageResource.getWidth()` functions are returning 0 for the first time I click the CellList item(handled via SingleSelectionModel) which executes the above snippet of code, and works perfectly from the second time I click the same list item. This happens for all the CellList items. I tried so many things but couldn't get it to work.

Could someone please help me out on what's going wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

While you are doing operations on `image` ,Actually its not Added to DOM.
You need to do that operation on that after it added to the DOM.

```
    Image image = new Image();
            image.addLoadHandler(new LoadHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onLoad(LoadEvent event) {
              //Do your operations on image .
       image.getElement().getStyle().setVisibility(Style.Visibility.Visible); 
                      }
                 });

    image.getElement().getStyle().setVisibility(Style.Visibility.HIDDEN); 
    RootPanel.get().add(image);
    image.setUrl(url);
```

You may get doubt about **Style.Visibility.Hidden and Visible**

**Reason**:If you are doing the changes on `image(resize)`,user can first see the original image and then resized image. To prevent that hide the ige first, Do the changes and Finally ***JUST SHOW IT***.

Answer (score 0):

`You can get the correct height and width of the image only if the image is already rendered in the UI`.

I guess you are trying to render the image on click. If so, for the first click the image is not already rendered. So it is returning 0 as height and width. First click onwards it returns proper values because the image is already rendered. So it works perfectly.

SOLUTION : Render the image along with CellList Items and control the image visibility with CSS visible or display property. On click you enable the image visibility with your calculated height and width.